# How to authenticate DCM account by using service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-python-client, double-click-advertising

I'm trying to download the report from DCM by using python client library. I'm using service account and using this link code [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/blob/master/python/v3_3/authenticate_using_service_account.py)!. I have followed all the steps to set up the service account file which is mentioned in DCM api url, but I'm getting below error while running the code.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 86, in _validate_clientsecrets
    (client_type, client_info), = clientsecrets_dict.items()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

I'm using below service account file to connect to the DCM api and download the reports. This is the process I'm trying to set up so that on daily basis the reports get download automatically without any manual intervention.

```
import argparse
import sys

from googleapiclient import discovery
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Declare command-line flags.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('path_to_service_account_json_file',help='Path to the service account JSON file to use for authenticating.')
argparser.add_argument('-i','--impersonation_email',help='Google account email to impersonate.')

# The OAuth 2.0 scopes to request.
OAUTH_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting']


def main(argv):
    # Retrieve command line arguments.
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,parents=[tools.argparser, argparser])
    flags = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])

    # Authenticate using the supplied service account credentials
    http = authenticate_using_service_account(flags.path_to_service_account_json_file,flags.impersonation_email)

    # Construct a service object via the discovery service.
    service = discovery.build('dfareporting', 'v3.3', http=http)

    try:
        # Construct the request.
        request = service.userProfiles().list()

        # Execute request and print response.
        response = request.execute()

        for profile in response['items']:
            print('Found user profile with ID %s and user name "%s".' %(profile['profileId'], profile['userName']))

    except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
        print('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run the ''application to re-authorize')

def authenticate_using_service_account(path_to_service_account_json_file,impersonation_email):
    """Authorizes an httplib2.Http instance using service account credentials."""
    # Load the service account credentials from the specified JSON keyfile.
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(path_to_service_account_json_file,scopes=OAUTH_SCOPES)

    # Configure impersonation (if applicable).
    if impersonation_email:
        credentials = credentials.create_delegated(impersonation_email)

    # Use the credentials to authorize an httplib2.Http instance.
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    return http


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

```
TypeError: cannot instantiate ctype 'EVP_MD_CTX' of unknown size
```

Comment: The error message is reporting that it expects Client Secrets and not service account credentials. However, the error message does not match your code.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I have posted the same exact error message which I had received after running the above code. I have used the same code and the steps mentioned on [this](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/service_accounts#examples) link. On this link it has been mentioned the use of service account to connect to the DCM.

Comment: The code that you included is using a service account. The error message line numbers do not match and the errors are for OAUTH FLOWS which are not in the code that you included. Perhaps you have named a file with the same name as an import? In any event, the error message wants Client Secrets and not a service account.

Comment: @JohnHanley, sorry for the confusion here, By mistake, I have posted the old code used for user account, I have updated my new code and also the error.

Comment: Your new error is an OpenSSL or BoringSSL configuration error. Make sure that each library is the latest version.

Comment: Comment on my last comment. Newer versions of OpenSSL changed how objects are allocated. The Google library might need an older version of OpenSSL - check the release date for outh2_cient. It might be old code that no longer works with today's libraries.